# Cocoa Pods not set up correctly for Swift/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, terminal, cocoapods

I recently tried installing Cocoa Pods. I typed this in terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoa pods
```

and it returned:

```
...
Done installing documentation for pods after 0 seconds
8 gems installed
```

So then I typed in:

```
 pod setup --verbose
```

and it returned this:

```
-bash: pod: command not found
```

Has anyone ever dealt with this?

Comment: it should be `sudo gem install cocoapods` without a whitespace

Comment: @luk2302 it still installed gems when I did with a white space. Should I just do it again without one?

Comment: yes and you should try to remove the ones that have been installed by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

rather than

```
sudo gem install cocoa pods
```

Comment: Okay, should I uninstall it first and then do it again?

Comment: I would just try again without the space.

Comment: Okay, this worked out! "Setup completed" Thank you!!